# Do asynchronous HttpApplication events wait until they return?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asynchronous, httpapplication

To what extent are HttpApplication async events (eg those registered using `AddOnEndRequestAsync` and friends) asynchronous? Does IIS wait for all asynchronous events fired for a particular event to complete before moving onto the next event, or are they 'fire and forget'?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me the exact workings when running in integrated pipeline mode, but I can tell you what I see for the non-integrated case, and the semantics should remain the same.

The short answer is that each event handler is fired in series, whether synchronous or asynchronous, and the next is not fired until the previous completes.

You can trace this through the source code.

A request comes in and is stored in a queue.  Typically, when the `HttpRuntime` dequeues a request, it initializes an `HttpApplication` for the request by calling its `InitInternal` method, passing the `HttpContext` as an argument.

`HttpApplication.InitInternal` initializes a new `HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager` class for the non-integrated-mode case.  You can then see it calls the `BuildSteps` method on it.  This creates an `ArrayList` to store the steps and constructs and stores all of the steps.  Specifically, these steps are implementations of an `IExecuteStep` interface.  Ultimately, when all of the steps are added, the list is finalized by copying it to an array and saving it for later in a member var `_execSteps`.

There are several sources for the steps, but the most used you'll see is the `HttpApplication.CreateEventExecutionSteps` which takes the event type (begin request, authorize, etc.) and the steps array to add its steps for that event in.  If you drill into `CreateEventExecutionSteps` you can see it adding an `IExecuteStep` for each async and sync handler it knows about, from the `AsyncEvents` and `Events` tables, respectively.  The `IExecuteStep` interface itself basically consists of an `Execute` method and a `CompletedSynchronously` flag.

Now, pause and look back at one of those Add methods like the one you mentioned, `AddOnEndRequestAsync`, and you can see it add info about the async handler to the `AsyncEvents` table.  `CreateEventExecutionSteps` will then walk through this table and an `AsyncEventExecutionStep` will be constructed for each handler added.

Back to the request flow.  After the `HttpRuntime` initializes the `HttpApplication` for the request, it calls its `BeginProcessRequest` method, which fires `ResumeSteps`.

`ResumeSteps` is the important one where you can see how the steps are used and what the wait strategy is in the async case.  You can see it maintaining a `_currentStepIndex` into the array of execution steps.  Eventually you see it grab the next step from the array and call its `Execute` method.  If the step reports that its execution `CompletedSynchronously`, it loops and goes again.  If not, it lets the method complete and enters into the async abyss.

To see what happens in this async case, you have to look at that `AsyncEventExecutionStep` implementation which was created for the async handlers.  In its `Execute` implementation, you see it fire the begin handler and pass in a completion callback.  In the constructor, you see this callback initialized to a method that eventually calls... `HttpApplication.ResumeSteps` again!

And so it keeps going, executing steps, sync or async, until the array is overrun at which point it "finishes" the request processing.

The point is, you can clearly see that steps, which translate to the event handlers you add, are executed one by one, and whether sync or async, the following steps are not executed until the current step completes.  Your question was whether events are handled one-by-one in this way, but as you can see, in fact it's even more granular, with each event handler being handled this way, so each gets synchronized access to the HttpContext and can operate without worrying about whether they are still "in the right phase" of the pipeline.

Obviously there's other details in that source code, yada yada, but this is the gist.